# ActionBar Up button: go to previous Activity with prev fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I need your help regarding my application flow.

```
MainActivity (with Navigation Drawer)
-- Fragment A
-- Fragment B
-- Fragment C (articles list view)

ArticleActivity
-- Fragment D (article detail view)
```

Fragment C (`MainActivity`) displays a list of items (`ListView`). Selecting an item leads to fragment D (handle by `ArticleActivity`) which presents that item in more detail.

Fragment D displays a "Up" button that should allow the user to returns to previous screen (the detail view). The problem is that when the "Up" button is pressed the previous activity is displayed but not the previous activated fragment (the defaut fragment (`A`) is instead displayed).

My current code:

```
public class FragmentC extends Fragment {
    public static FragmentC newInstance() {
        FragmentC fragment = new FragmentC();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_courses, container, false);

        ...
        // Somewhere in my code I have a onClickListener to launch the detail view activity
        setOnClickListener(new OnCardClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("articleIndex", mArticle.getId());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        ...

        return view;
    }
}

public class ArticleActivity extends Activity {
    private long mArticleIndex;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_course);

        mArticleIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("articleIndex", 0);

        // Set up action bar:
        // Specify that the Home button should show an "Up" caret, indicating that touching the
        // button will take the user one step up in the application's hierarchy.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Place an ArticleFragment as our content pane
        ArticleFragment fragment = ArticleFragment.newInstance(mArticleIndex);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This is called when the Home (Up) button is pressed in the action bar.
                Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                upIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(upIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

I think that I can resolve this issue by passing parameters to my `Intent`. For example `i.putExtra("displayFragment", FragmentD)` and then on the MainActivity retrieve it and tell to the `FragmentManager` to display the wanted fragment. I do not know if it's can work.

But it's maybe not the right way to achieve that?

Do you have any better workaround?

Comment: I have solved my problem, it was infact simple. On the `Intent` of `ArticleActivity` we need to add the following flags: `upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`.

Comment: It reloads Fragment. Have you figured out how to avoid that and get last state of that fragment?

Comment: Never Mind i figured out. Your answer is helpful.

Comment: @Roon13 How did you manage to do it ? can you give me some hint ?

Comment: @k2ibegin Instead of using fragment i used just Activity without fragment. `if (id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            upIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(upIntent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }`

Comment: so you create that activity again on up button click ?

Comment: @k2ibegin See Guicara's answer and his comment. I just made small changes. I put SINGLE TOP in Androidmanifest instead of setting up that in above code. This actually worked for me. So I do hope it will work for you.

Comment: @k2ibegin no it doesnt create that activity again because of SINGLE TOP in Manifest. In my case MainActivity doesnt reload. Tell me if u need more help.

Comment: Thanks ! I have a situation because of navigation drawer implementation. I start each activity and do stuff in its container fragment, now the problem is that if i am deep down the heirarchy, and if i click top button on a fragment held by activity B, I go back directly to activity A but I want to go back to activity's A fragment (because Activity A fragment is the initiator of my activity B). The back button press works perfectly fine. I understood your point but I am just thinking if it is possible to get back to activity A's fragment just as happens when I press back button !